# Singular value decomposition, same matrix in different orthonormal bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If one considers the matrix $A$ of a linear mapping from an $n$ dimensional space to an $m$ dimensional space, how can one show that the matrix $S$, where $A=USV^{H}$ is the SVD, corresponds to the same mapping in a different orthonormal basis?

I don't know if this is trivially easy to see, i.e. that $U$ and $V$ will change the basis and they are orthonormal? I guess my problem is that in most cases when I've worked with changing basis it has been for square matrices like $B=SCS^{-1}$ where $S$ is a transition matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U$ and $V$ are still square matrices, containing the second basis as their column vectors (coordinating in the original basis), $V$ in the source and $U$ in the target space. We also have that $V$ is orthonormal iff $V^{-1}=V^H$.